# Display running total with previous value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
Array
    (
    [2013-03-12] => Array
        (
            [total_clicks] => 2266
            [total_unique_clicks] => 177
        )

    [2013-03-19] => Array
        (
            [total_clicks] => 2647
            [total_unique_clicks] => 241
        )

    [2013-03-20] => Array
        (
            [total_clicks] => 2656
            [total_unique_clicks] => 245
        )
     )
```

Now I am using the following code for displaying the values

```
$current=strtotime($from);
$last=strtotime($to);
while($last >= $current){
    $current_date=date("Y-m-d",$last);
    echo $daily_click[$current_date]['total_unique_clicks'];
    $last=strtotime("-1 day",$last);
}
```

This is displaying the values but if there is no value for a date say '2013-03-18' I need to display the previous value from the array that is with the index 2013-03-12 and the value is 177. It is actually a running total and so i need to display this for other dates with out values. That is it should display the previous count until it is changed. how can I do this ?

I need this order for the dates as I need to show from the latest date first and decreasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// get an array of the recorded dates in descending order
$descDateOrder = $daily_click;
ksort($descDateOrder);
$descDateOrder = array_keys(array_reverse($descDateOrder));

$current=strtotime($from);
$last=strtotime($to);

// initialize to the most recent date <= $last
$prev_key = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($descDateOrder); $i++) {
    if (strtotime($descDateOrder[$i]) <= $last) {
        $prev_key = $i;
        break;
    }
}

while($last >= $current) {
    $current_date=date("Y-m-d",$last);

    if ($descDateOrder[$prev_key] == $current_date) {
        // use oldest date if we go past it (could break instead, to stop)
        $prev_key = min(count($descDateOrder) - 1, $prev_key + 1);
    } else {
        $current_date = $descDateOrder[$prev_key];
    }

    echo $daily_click[$current_date]['total_unique_clicks'];

    $last=strtotime("-1 day",$last);
}
```

Comment: Almost correct.But for some days initially the count is zero. So it should show zero there. That is before 2013-03-12 total_unique_clicks is zero. Now it is showing  the value 177 there.

Comment: The thing is that if the previous value is non zero , then it should show the value. If it is zero, it has to show zero itself as there is no count untill that date.

Comment: I have added another condition that is if(strtotime($descDateOrder[$prev_key])>strtotime($last_element)) where the last_element is the last element of $descDateOrder array. The dates which are previous to this is checked and given zero as the value.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
$current=strtotime($from);
$last=strtotime($to);

$array_key = array_keys($daily_click);
arsort($array_key);

while($last >= $current){
$current_date=date("Y-m-d",$last);
            if($daily_click[$current_date]['total_unique_clicks'] != '')
            {
                echo $daily_click[$current_date]['total_unique_clicks'];
            }
            else
            {
                foreach( $array_key as $value)
                {
                    if(strtotime($current_date) > strtotime($value))
                    {
                       $was_last_found = $value;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                echo $daily_click[$was_last_found]['total_unique_clicks'];
            }
            $last=strtotime("-1 day",$last);
}
```

Comment: But the thing is that the order is different here. So I think this will not give correct results.

Comment: that is it will display the value of 19 th first as it satisfy the if condition and the $was_last is 2013-03-19. Then for the date 2013-03-18, this will show $daily_click[2013-03-19]. But I need to show $daily_click[2013-03-12] on 18th as it is the sum upto 19 on that date the sum is changed. So from 12th to 18th I need to show the value of 12th

Comment: @AlwinAugustin Ohh I didnt realised that .. I have edited my code according to your requirement. Hope it helps you .. have a look

Answer (score 0):

```
krsort($daily_clicks);
foreach($daily_clicks as $date => $val) {
  if($date <= $to && $date >= $from)
      echo $val['total_unique_clicks'];
}
```

Comment: If I understand the question, it needs to print something for each intervening day between `$to` and `$from`

Comment: The thing is that if the previous value is non zero , then it should show the value. If it is zero, it has to show zero itself as there is no count untill that date